# How to include jquery in masterpage header without path problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, header, master-pages

I have tried this

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Back Office</title>
<link href="~/Styles/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

The error message is

[image]

I think too much, it is just find using this
    
sorry

Comment: I have copy your line from your question and check, I am not getting an issue.

Comment: You don't need to resolve the URL on your resources...

Comment: Yes, i'm just found out that it is just fine using this
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Muhammad i use visual studio 2010, asp.net 4. I don't know it might be some different.

Comment: yes, I have check in VS 2010 and asp.net 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, you are trying to add controls to page dynamically. In this case, you can use the below code

```
var control = new HtmlGenericControl("script") ;
control.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
control.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"));
//CDN will be best while hosting the application
//control.Attributes.Add("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js");
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: Yes, You can put this at Page_Load.

Comment: The header required before page load has been load, this is not work too but thank.

Comment: If you like to keep the script at first. You can use `AddAt` function  `this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, control)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using DataBinding with ResolveUrl

```
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then in your code behind call the Header's Databind

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.Header.DataBind();
    }
```

If you start getting errors regarding the ViewState you may need to disable it on the header.

```
<head runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
```