# Different between link prefix "~/" and "/"

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, prefix

Sometime we need to put / or ~/ as the suffix in order to make refer to the root

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Styles/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is what i know from Phill

~/ is not valid unless you have a runat attribute on your control/element. '/' by itself specifies to the browser to look from the root directory, so if you link to '/css/main.css' from www.mysite.com/product/view.aspx it will look for the css file in www.mysite.com/css/main.css. When you use '~/' with runat-server, it will work out the path to the directory at runtime, so in the same example with '~/css/main.css' the rendered url will look like '../css/main.css' because it needs to drop the directory back 1 before finding the directory 'css'. (hope that makes sense) – Phill 
[How to include jquery in masterpage header without path problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093135/how-to-include-jquery-in-masterpage-header-without-path-problems/6093216#6093216)

but as i has tried, even i use / firefox still refer to ../../ instead of static path.
also, I don't know it clearly how to use it correctly , which one use on which situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/ refers to virtual directory application root where as "/" refers to site roots eg if you have site that in http://www.example.com/ and which has http://www.example.com/foo where folder "foo" configured as virtual directory [application in IIS](http://www.onlinehowto.net/Tutorials/Windows-2003-Server/Set-an-application-folder-in-IIS-on-Windows-server/1450) a page in  http://www.example.com/foo/foo.aspx will resolve ~/ as relative to virtual directory application root directory which is  http://www.example.com/foo but "/" will still resolve to site root which is http://www.example.com/

Answer (score 3):

The `/` at the beginning of a relative URL backs up to the root of the hostname.

The prefix `~/` in a relative URL can only be interpreted by the ASP.NET process, which is why it only works for `runat=server`. It is translated upon output to refer to the root URL of the *ASP.NET application*. Many times, this is the same as the root of the hostname, but it *will* differ if the ASP.NET application that the code is running in is a virtual directory in IIS rather than its own site.

If you only need to drop one directory level back, you can use "../" as the prefix rather than "/" or "~/".